# Checking multiple values (and) in a node in Xpath

Tags: xslt, xpath

XML:

```
<codes>
    <code>AP</code>
    <code>BS</code>
</codes
```

I am trying to check `<code>` if it contains both 'AP' and 'BS' using following xpath.

```
/codes[contains(code, 'AP') and contains(code, 'BS')]
```

but is not working. Is there any other way to get to the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
/codes[code='AP' and code='BS']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really need `contains` but not `exactly equal`,  use such Xpath

```
/codes[code[contains(., 'AP')] and code[contains(., 'BS')]]
```